# my web scraping program too long time to run, how can i make it more efficient?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I started learing programming a few months ago, and i have recently been working on this web scraping program. When i run it, it searches all the news articles for keywords and picks out the ones that include them. Currently it takes around 26 seconds to scan through all 43 of them.

`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
import imghdr


emailAdress = emailReciver


conn = sqlite3.connect('artikler.db')
c = conn.cursor()

try:
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE artikler (tittel text, dato text, url text)")
except:
    pass


source = requests.get("https://www.tynsetingen.no/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

keywords = ['strøm', 'nøk', 'vindmølle', 'vindkraft', 'nord-østerdal kraftlag', 'solceller', 'solcelle']


ac = soup.find('div', id='front-page')
anchorPoints = ac.find_all('a')
articles = list()


for link in anchorPoints:
    url = link.get('href')
    if url.startswith('https://www.tynsetingen.no/'):
        if not "/category/" in url:
            articles.append(url)


for article in articles:
    Asource = requests.get(article).text
    Asoup = BeautifulSoup(Asource, 'lxml')

    try:
        line = Asoup.find('meta', property='article:published_time')
        dateandtime = line.get('content').split('T')
        date = dateandtime[0]

        info = Asoup.find('header', class_='entry-header')
        UnfilteredTitle = info.find('h1', class_='entry-title').text
        title = UnfilteredTitle.lower()
        UnfilteredCaption = info.find('figcaption', class_="wp-caption-text").text
        caption = UnfilteredCaption.lower()
    except:
        continue

    report = "En relevant artikkel i Tynsetingen har blitt publisert!"
    content = '''En ny artikkel som kan være relevant for deg har akkurat blitt publisert: "{}"\n
    Klikk på linken under for å lese den.\n
    {}'''.format(UnfilteredTitle, article)

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = report
    msg['From'] = "oftenvetle@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = emailAdress
    msg.set_content(content)


    for word in keywords:
        if word in title or word in caption:
            relevant = True
        else:
            relevant = False
            continue

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM artikler WHERE url=?", (article,))
    if c.fetchone() == None and relevant:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO artikler VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, date, article))
        conn.commit()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login("email", "password")
            smtp.send_message(msg)
```

`

Are there any ways i could make my program quicker?

Comment: you can make your searches run in multiple threads: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/

Comment: 26 seconds for 43 consecutive requests? Not bad, actually. You may consider using `threading` standard library or other thread-based parallel solution to make requests in parallel, if you need it faster. Mutliprocessing would be an overhead here, threads should be sufficient.

Comment: `asyncio` or `threading` come to mind immediately for multiple `i/o` operations....

Comment: I really dont need my program fast, however i thought i had some obvious inefficiencies, since my program uses 26 seconds to scan 43 html pages while search engines uses 0,5 seconds to scan millions. Though, Im aware that there are alot of differences between my program that runs on my PC and Google.